# How to transform a list into a set in LISP?

Tags: list, set, lisp, common-lisp

I have been trying to transform a linear list into a set but with no avail. Everytime I run this, I get some weird compilation errors like "badly formed lambda" which points to the way I use append. Here is my code:

```
(defun mem(e l)
  (cond
      ((null l) nil)
      ((equal e (car l)) t)
      ((listp (car l)) (mem e (car l)))
      (t(mem e (cdr l)))
  )
)

(defun st(l k)
  (cond
      ((null l) nil)
      (( mem '(car l) 'k) (st (cdr l) k))
      ((listp (car l)) (st (car l) k))
      ( t (st (cdr l) (append((car l) k)) ))
      (t(mem e (cdr l)))
  )
)
```

EDIT: frankly I just want to remove the duplicates from list l

Answer (score 7):

### Prefer Standard Library Functions

> *EDIT: frankly I just want to remove the duplicates from list l*

Common Lisp has a [**remove-duplicates**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm) function.  The documentation inclues examples:

> #### Examples:
>
> ```
> (remove-duplicates "aBcDAbCd" :test #'char-equal :from-end t) =>  "aBcD"
> (remove-duplicates '(a b c b d d e)) =>  (A C B D E)
> (remove-duplicates '(a b c b d d e) :from-end t) =>  (A B C D E)
> (remove-duplicates '((foo #\a) (bar #\%) (baz #\A))
>     :test #'char-equal :key #'cadr) =>  ((BAR #\%) (BAZ #\A))
> (remove-duplicates '((foo #\a) (bar #\%) (baz #\A)) 
>     :test #'char-equal :key #'cadr :from-end t) =>  ((FOO #\a) (BAR #\%))
> ```

### Are you trying to flatten the list too?

From your code for **mem**, where you do:

```
  ((listp (car l)) (mem e (car l)))
```

it looks like you want your member function to also recurse into sublists.  That's a bit questionable, even when working with sets, since sets can traditionally include other sets.  E.g., {{3},{4},5} is a set containing 5, the set {3}, and the set {4}.  It's *not* the same as the set {3,4,5}.  Your **st** function also looks like it's trying to recurse into lists, which makes it seem like you want to *flatten* you lists, too.  Again, that's a bit questionable, but if you want to do that, then your conversion to a set would be easier as a "flatten, then remove duplicates" process:

```
(defun flatten (list)
  "Returns a fresh list containing the leaf elements of LIST."
  (if (listp list)
      (mapcan 'flatten list)
      (list list)))

;; CL-USER> (flatten '(1 2 (3 4) 5 ((6))))
;; (1 2 3 4 5 6)

(defun to-set (list)
  "Returns a set based on the elements of LIST.  The result
is a flat list containing the leaf elements of LIST, but
with any duplicate elements removed."
  (delete-duplicates (flatten list)))

;; CL-USER> (to-set '(1 3 (3 4) ((4) 5)))
;; (1 3 4 5)
```

### Notes

> *I get some weird compilation errors like "badly formed lambda" which points to the way I use append.*

Yes, you're trying to call **append** like: **(append((car l) k))**.  That's actually not a problem for **append**.  Remember, the syntax for a function call in Lisp is **(function argument…)**.  That means that you've got:

```
(append      ((car l) k))
 <function>  <argument1>
```

But your *argument1* is also a function call:

```
((car l)     k          )
 <function>  <argument1>
```

In Common Lisp, you can't use **(car l)** as a function.  The only thing that can appear for a *function* is a symbol (e.g., **car**, **append**) or a lambda expression (e.g., **(lambda (x) (+ x 1)**).

You want to call **(append (car l) k)** instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, CL does not have a `set` data type.
[Lists, however, can be used as sets](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_abb.htm), you do not need to write any special code for that.

Second, I don't understand what your `st` function is supposed to do, but I bet that in the second `cond` clause you should *not* quote `(car l)` and `k`. You should use meaningful names for your functions and avoid abbreviations. As per your explanation in the comment, you should use [`pushnew`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_pshnew.htm) instead.

Third, your `mem` function is quite weird, I am pretty sure you do not mean what you wrote: `e` is searched along a path in the *tree* `l`, not in the *list* `l`. As per your explanation in the comment, you should check *both* `car` and `cdr`:

```
(defun tree-member (tree element &key (test #'eql))
  (if (consp tree)
      (or (tree-member (car tree) element :test test)
          (tree-member (cdr tree) element :test test))
      (funcall test element tree)))
```

Comment: the mem function is used for deciding wether an element "e" is within a linnear or nested list. 
with st, I'm trying to add the elements from list l to list k, without having duplicates